# What's the minimum clearance from drywall when installing rigid duct work?

Tags: code-compliance, ducts

What's the minimum clearance required when installing rigid duct work on vertical walls with drywall and 2x2 framing.

If I don't install drywall behind the rigid duct work for which there's only 1/2" of clearance, can I install mineral wool in the wall cavity?

I will build a soffit using 2 x 2's spacing them 1" away from the ductwork on two sides to the left of the duct and the front of the ductwork

[image: bathroom wall to install Duct work]

[image: Drawing]

Comment: Is this ductwork for environmental air? Or is it for combustion exhaust?

Comment: Its from the Furnace in the basement

Comment: They had a 7" Round Duck, but it takes up to much space, next to the toilet, with that said it will have a 3.43" clearance from the Right side of Toliet Tank with New drywall and 2x2's to cover the 7" Ductwork it's OD Dimensions are 11.56" Wide with the 7" Round Duct inside it.

Comment: Looked at your question for the second time!  No to Both Questions! My Old (1992) Gas Furnance blows hot air from its blower to its attached plenum above the furnace. there's a 2" PVC Pipe Attached to the Furnance in the basement it exists in my basement through the exterior wall.

Comment: So, at the bottom the long face of the duct is parallel to the brick pillar, however at the top the duct is shown with the duct long face perpendicular to the pillar. How are you going to achieve this? Or is this an Escher diagram?

Comment: Have no idea what an Escher Diagram is? I've assembled several 3.25 x 10 x 36" Rectangular Ducts to reach my desired length and added (2) 10-in x 3.25-in x 7-in Galvanized Steel Straight Stack Duct Boot at each end.  you can buy them at Lowes or Home Depot

Comment: One thing to note is that you are reducing the area from ~38.5" to 32.5" with your proposed rectangle duct replacing the 7".   If that is feeding a single location it probably isn't a notable issue but any reduction in size can increase pressure and/or reduce airflow volume.

Comment: @Jeff84634 SolarMike is saying the orientation of the duct at the floor is 90 degrees from where the duct is at the ceiling. It looks physically impossible like this https://mcescher.com/gallery/most-popular/#iLightbox[gallery_image_1]/18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [DrSparks answered](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/235619/whats-the-minimum-clearance-to-drywall-when-installing-ridgid-duct-work/235623#235623), no clearance is needed for this. HVAC people will even sometimes even use part of a joist (or other) cavity itself as part of the air path when doing retrofit work, and there isn't another way to get the ducting into the space.

Comment: You have enough rep now, please delete your "not an answer" and make it a comment in the appropriate location.

Comment: @FreeMan If he deletes his answer, he will lose the rep and thus the ability to comment on others' posts. The information about going through framing members is also worth the answer standing on its own, I think.

Comment: What's a rep mean? Is Rep an Acronym? I'm brand new to this site.

Comment: @Jeff84634 "Rep" is an abbreviation for "reputation", which is the Stack Exchange Network's name for the points which [accumulate from votes on your questions and answers and various actions (editing, accepting answers, having an answer accepted, and bounties)](/help/whats-reputation). The amount of reputation is used for [various privileges on the site](/help/privileges), including the [comment everywhere](/help/privileges/comment) privilege at 50 reputation. Prior to having >= 50 reputation, a user can only comment on their own posts and any answers posted on their own question.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need any clearance for drywall and environmental air ducts. It could be touching it if you wanted. Heck, you could glue the drywall to the ducts if you wanted to

Comment: but can the ducts hold up the roof? That is the real question... Finally I get to realize my dream of building a house out of only ducts!

Comment: @user253751 As long is it is a duct roof you'll be fine.